# How can I get every user info in code in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How can I get access to every meteor user object? I tried this, but it shows Meteor.users does not have function forEach.

```
Meteor.users.forEach((user) => {
    console.log("userId", user._id);
});
```

Then I tried this, but it says userId is `undefined`.

```
_.toArray(Meteor.users).forEach((user) => {
    console.log("userId", user._id);
});
```

So how can I get it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Meteor.users` is a Mongo collection. Mongo collections provide the `map` method to iterate through all found elements, but first, you have to find them. If you want to map through all the users without exception, just map without arguments, like this:

```
Meteor.users.find().map(user => console.log(user));
```

There, `user` will be an object that represents a user, i.e. similar to what you retrieve with `Meteor.user()`.

Another way to iterate through all users would be to first fetch them in an instance of Array and then apply lodash or underscore to it:

```
const users = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
_.map(users, user => console.log(user));
```

Comment: You'll also want to make sure you're publishing and subscribing to all users, otherwise you're only going to get the currently logged in user unless you have auto-publish turned on.